# URI to image file which is local for selected library

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, uri

My solution consists of two projects:
- Windows Phone 8.1 Application
- Class library for Windows Phone 8.1

In the application I have a `XAML` file with a `ControlTemplate` called `MyControlTemplate`. `MyControlTemplate` has `<Image Source="{Binding Image}">`

In my class library I have a `Page` with a control which uses `MyControlTemplate`. `MyControlTemplate` uses `DataContext` class which has an `Image` property which returns `URI` to files with images.

Files with images are in `Assets` folder which is set locally in the class library.

The problem is that when binding comes to `Image` property to get selected image the path creating new `URI` does not point to `Assets` folder which is in class library.

My current solution is:

```
private static Uri _baseUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets");
```

to be used then in:

```
public Uri Image
    {
        get
        {
            return new Uri(SampleDataCommon._baseUri, this._picture);
        }
    }
```

where `this._picture` is set to `@".\Assets\cliff.jpg"`

It actually works i.e. it gets images but from `Shared\Assets` project folder but not a `Assets` folder of the class library which is what I want to achieve.

Any help with the `URI`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> If you are using LinkedResource() in C# it is most likely not to
>   pickup your relative URI or the file location.
>
> You can use some extra piece of code

```
        var outPutDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);

        var logoimage = Path.Combine(outPutDirectory, "Images\\logo.png");

        string relLogo = new Uri(logoimage).LocalPath;

        var logoImage = new LinkedResource(relLogo)
```

> Now it will pickup your relative path, convert this to absolute path
>   in memory and it will help you get the images.

From *[How to set relative path to Images directory inside C# project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15696812/how-to-set-relative-path-to-images-directory-inside-c-sharp-project)*

Looks like it will allow you to link the images in the way you're looking for.

Comment: `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` does not seem to be working on Windows Phone 8.1

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved the problem:

```
private static Uri _baseUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///nameOfTheProject/Assets/");
```